# Select from table A , and set it In table B which value does not exist Custom JPA Query

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

> I want to update the value of  withdraw table when user deposit the
> material. Deposit Material quantity deduct from last time How many
> material withdraw by the user. AND store the remaining material in
> pending column of  materialReturn table. When call the update api the
> pending value of materialReturn table set in the piece column of
> materialReturn table.[image]

> MateriaWithdraw table
> [image]

> Here is the my query

```
package com.nilmani.workmanagement.repository


import com.nilmani.workmanagement.entity.MaterialReturn
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
import javax.transaction.Transactional

interface MaterialReturnRepository : JpaRepository<MaterialReturn?, Long?> {

    /**update the material-withdraw table*/
    @Query("select m.pending from MaterialReturn as m and update WithdrwMaterial where m.depositId=:depositId")
     fun udpdateWithdrawMaterial(@RequestParam("depositId")depositId:Long): Long

}
```

> But this query is not working

Answer (score 3):

The update query should look like this:

```
UPDATE Withdraw_Material 
SET column_name = (SELECT mr.pending FROM Material_Return mr WHERE mr.depositId = depositId) 
WHERE clause (i dont seems to get the clause youre trying to use)
```